# Matlab function switching return/no return

Tags: matlab, return

In **Matlab**, I've got a function that is called after some special points are found on an image. Depending on how the nearby pixels of that "special point" are, the function must **return a structure** with many parameters **or return nothing**.

Is it possible to have a function that by deafult will return something but, in some cases, nothing should be returned? How that "return nothing"'s code should be like? Thank you.

Comment: You can return an empty array `[]`.

Comment: Alternatively, you could return an empty structure, _i.e_ a `struct` without fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One common trick in matlab is to use the empty matrix `[]` to indicate nothing. You could write your function something like (untested code):

```
function result = analyze(image, special_point)

% your code here

if pixels_are_ok
    result.a = 1;
    result.b = 2;
else
    result = [];
end
```

If you call this function from your other code, you can use isempty to see if you got a result or not:

```
result = analyze(image, special_point)

if isempty(result)
    display('did not find anything')
else
    display('found some interesting results')
    display(result)
end
```

Comment: Thank you. I had already tried to return an empty array. However, the use of "isempty" function in your code is actually what I need and what solves my problem. Thank you for giving me this other perspective.